# Click a button in another application

Tags: c#

I want yo use `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` to press a button in another app

i have a sample code to do this  by getting Window Handle, but it doesn't work

also i used "WinDowse"  to get required info. here is the code

```
private const uint BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
private const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
private const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

private void PushOKButton(IntPtr ptrWindow)
{
    WindowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Form1"); 
    if (ptrWindow == IntPtr.Zero)
      return;

    IntPtr ptrOKButton = FindWindowEx(ptrWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Yes");

    if (ptrOKButton == IntPtr.Zero)
      return;

    SendMessage(ptrOKButton, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(ptrOKButton, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(ptrOKButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
}
```

is There a Compelete Suloution in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right general idea.
There are always tricks to automation.

Button Down/Up  is preatty close to the raw action of clicking, but not quite the same.
You will want to consider

1. the coords where you click - some buttons don't like edge clicks at 0,0
2. position of the mouse - mouse outside of the button at start or end can cause it to not work
3. time to click - sometimes a quick click is ignored, add a small delay of say 10ms

BM_Click is an extra win32 message that is sent when doing a mouse click on a button - it's the shorter method and easier if the controls are the right type to use this alone.

Some effort is made to prevent things like using WM_GetText on password edits from foreign apps, be wary you may also have issues depending on the destination app.

Unfortunately I have no C# sample code for you right now.

Perhaps you might look into [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) to save some time.

Comment: *"You have the right general idea."* - Well, no. The idea is as wrong as it gets. Messages are just the observable part of input processing. If you replay just that part, you'll wind up with inconsistent state. The real answer is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: The .Net UI Automation framework is limited, and causes a variety of artefacts - such as Adobe reader prompting for accessibility mode if you even look sideways the windows it displays.
We have been crashing many Microsoft applications trying to use UI Automation because of bugs in the target apps where custom control creation hasn't covered automation support properly.

Comment: UI Automation is exposed through COM objects, that are easily consumable from .NET, in case pre-built library support isn't sufficient. Your comment indicates that you answered a different question: *"Assuming that UI Automation doesn't work for us, what are the alternatives?"* The OP never claimed that UI Automation wouldn't work for them, so it should be considered first. And if you need to fake input, you really need to do it right. Sending messages won't do (see [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903)).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an Example of using the win32 API to drive the mouse - actually used for drag and drop selection of an area, but you could change the coords to mouse down/up inside the button.

```
POINT p;
BOOL cursorPosGetSuccessful = GetCursorPos(&p);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, horA, verA, NULL, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, horB, verB, NULL, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
if (cursorPosGetSuccessful)// put the mouse back to roughly where it used to be before the scan.  
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, p.x, p.y, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: assume i have these : mouse coords,window caption,window handle,window class name, can u leave a complete code ?

Comment: Straight from [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx): *"This function has been superseded. Use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead."* Neither one allows you to control a specific process; input always goes to the foreground process. As noted on your other answer (why did you feel the compelling need to post two anyway?): The real answer is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Second post was due to different possible answer.