# c# user32 dll - handler and sendmessage (whdl,BM_CLICK,intptr.zero,intptr.zero)

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get handler over a skype user window and click send file or call button using SendMessage(whdl,BM_CLICK,intptr.zero,intrptr.zero,intptr.zero). I get the handle over skype window, but I can;t het a handle over a button and click it using sendmessage. why> can someone help me. thx

Comment: You need to pinvoke EnumChildWindows() to get the handle of the button.  Hard to get right, consider something like AutoIt instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click a button in another application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009557/click-a-button-in-another-application)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say specifically with Skype, but the ChatControl on the Skype Window appears to be drawn mostly using GDI+ with proper logic, thus no child 'controls'. This is common for custom shaped or skinned look and feel in apps to do everything via GDI+ and mouse/location logic rather then using controls as it slows performance if rendering.

So in short, no this wouldn't be possible with Skype in its current build.